# How to "get" the size of the section header

Tags: formatting

I've got to format some text in the style of the section header. So what I would like to do is sort of "get" the parameters that define the section header (i.e. size, formatting, fontstyle) and apply that to the text. However, I'm too much of a newbie in tex and googling didn't really help me out.

I'd rally appreciate hints :-)

Comment: as in “read the source and copy it”, or do you want a macro that works out what’s in the current definition of `\section` and proceeds from there?

Comment: More like read the source size, source format and source font (latter if necessary) and the apply it to the text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current font identifier can be accessed to with `\the\font`. So this works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\getsectionfont}{\setbox0=\vbox{\section*{a\xdef\TheSectionFont{\the\font}}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\getsectionfont}

\begin{document}
\section{Some text just to see the result}

The following quotation will use the section font
\begin{quotation}\TheSectionFont
Some text just to see the result
\end{quotation}

\end{document}
```

We typeset a mock section title without printing it, but we use it to access the font. It's better to do it "at begin document" so all packages have been loaded.

The two lines should be the last before `\begin{document}`; with them you'll have the declaration `\TheSectionFont` to choose the font available also in definitions you make before those two lines (provided they don't typeset any text).

---

Just some more information. We need the low level `\xdef` because we want that

1. the meaning of `\TheSectionFont` is known outside the `\vbox` which makes a group;
2. the combination `\the\font` is expanded at the moment of the definition.

`\xdef` is equivalent to `\global\edef`; with a simple `\def` this wouldn't work, because `\the\font` always refers to the current font. On the other hand, `\the` can be expanded and when followed by `\font` the expansion is precisely the internal command that TeX uses to select the current font.

Comment: And... if I need to access the value in a macro?

Comment: @EgorHans Isn't `\TheSectionFont` what you want?

Comment: Oh, overlooked the last paragraph of the first part. Then it's all fine.

Comment: One more quick question: Is applying it to chapters and parts as trivial as one would expect, i.e. just replacing `\section*` with `\chapter*` or `\part*`, respectively?