# Changing font size for one section heading

Tags: sectioning, formatting, fontsize

I want to have a single `\subsection` printed significantly larger, without otherwise changing the font. This is for a landscape page, to put a subsection title before a full-page diagram, and it needs to be included in the table of contents.

I tried using

```
\huge{\subsection{Big subsection heading}}
```

but it doesn't modify the text at all.

Ideally, the solution would use the existing font (rather than hardcoding a font choice which matches the font in this example).

So I tried creating the table-of-contents entry with `\nosubsection` (custom), and then using `\thesubsection` with the title to create a 'fake' subsection heading.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% don't recall source
\newcommand{\nosubsection}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{subsection}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}#1}%
  \markright{#1}}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73158/how-to-get-the-size-of-the-section-header
\newcommand{\getsubsectionfont}{\setbox0=\vbox{\subsection*{a\xdef\TheSubsectionFont{\the\font}}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\getsubsectionfont}


\begin{document}

\section{Section heading}
\subsection{Normal subsection heading}

% Note the separate \centering
\nosubsection{Big subsection heading}
\centering{\TheSubsectionFont\huge{\thesubsection{} Big subsection heading}}
\label{sec:big}

% Don't know why this is centred too, but it doesn't matter
\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```

MWE output:

[image: MWE output]

Comment: It accomplishes the same thing, thank you. I'm inclined to use @GonzaloMedina's solution because it seems less 'hacky', but yours is usable too. If you submit it as an answer I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option using [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) to define two commands to switch at will between the desired formatting:; use `\largesubsection` as many times as desired and at any point, to switch to the larger format; `\stdsection` switches back to the regular format.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\stdsubsection{%
  \titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
}
\newcommand\largesubsection{%
  \titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section heading}
\subsection{Normal subsection heading}

\largesubsection
\subsection{Big subsection heading}
\lipsum[66]

\stdsubsection
\subsection{Another normal subsection heading}

\end{document}
```

With `\titleformat*`, the code simplifies a little:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\stdsubsection{%
  \titleformat*{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}
}
\newcommand\largesubsection{%
  \titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\filcenter}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section heading}
\subsection{Normal subsection heading}

\largesubsection
\subsection{Big subsection heading}
\lipsum[66]

\stdsubsection
\subsection{Another normal subsection heading}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm surprised by how different the "big" font is from the others, but adding `bfseries` to `\largesubsection` makes it look more like the others. Is this an unavoidable consequence of the bolded/unbolded fonts?

Comment: @DavidLord I suppressed the boldface from the larger headings because it seemed too much (`\huge` size bold-faced titles stand too much for my liking), but you can, of course, add `\bfseries`. I am afraid I don't understand what do you mean by the unavoidable consequence. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Poorly-phrased on my part: the character of the font seems quite different with bold and unbold. Fortunately, in my use case the bold is useful (the secton heading needs to stand out on the page against a diagram), so this is perfect with the addition of `\bfseries`. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidLord You're welcome! Ah, now I see what you meant. I added `\bfseries` in my updated answer and provided a shorter version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Gonzalo Medina's answer is a good start, but I think it can be improved on in two or three ways.  We don't really want two `\titleformat` definitions that need to be kept in sync – that's fine for a MWE, but not in an evolving real-world document where the definitions are likely to be more complicated.  It seems to me that it would be better if we could scoping to avoid having to reset the style to its original value, or even better, if we could select the style automatically.  This MWE does this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand\ssectstyle{\large}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\bfseries\ssectstyle}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd\landscape{\renewcommand\ssectstyle{\huge\filcenter}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\section{Section heading}
\subsection{Normal subsection heading}

\begin{landscape}
\subsection{Big subsection heading}
\end{landscape}

\subsection{Another normal subsection heading}
\end{document}
```

This pulls out the parts of the heading style that vary into a new `\ssectstyle` command, so only this needs to be redefined.  Because TeX macro definitions are scoped, if we do

```
{\renewcommand\ssectstyle{\huge\filcenter} \subsection{Huge}}
```

... then the definition returns to its original value at the end of that block.  The same is true if we do it inside an environment, e.g.:

```
\begin{landscape}
\renewcommand\ssectstyle{\huge\filcenter}
\subsection{Big subsection heading}
\end{landscape}
```

This solution goes one step further by patching the `\landscape` command which starts the landscape environment so that it automatically applies this style change.